# How to Groupby and calculate max based on filter in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So, i have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to groupby based on Field1, if count is greater than 2, then find max Field2 and create a new field and set it to True.

[image]

I tried

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_csv("c:/test.csv")
df["Field3"] = df.groupby(["Field1"])["Field2"].transform("max")
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to do an additional `transform` to check the counts per `Field1` which are greater than `2`

```
g = df.groupby("Field1")["Field2"]
df['Field3'] = g.transform('count').gt(2) & df['Field2'].eq(g.transform('max'))
```

Alternatively you can also use the single `transform` with lambda function to check for the conditions but this might be slower that the first approach on larger dataframes

```
df['Field3'] = df.groupby("Field1")["Field2"].transform(
                         lambda s: (s == max(s)) * (len(s) > 2))
```

---

```
  Field1  Field2  Field3
0      a       3   False
1      a       5    True
2      a       3   False
3      b       2   False
4      c       1   False
5      b       6   False
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham Sharma. So, how to calculate (df["Field3"] - df["Field4"]) for each row with count > 2 ?

Comment: Can i use np.where ?

Comment: @bibiji What is `Field4`? I don't see any column named `Field4` in your sample data.

Comment: Suppose i have 1 more column with integer type.

Comment: @bibiji Can you please ask another question on Stackoverflow with the new requirements? I'm sure that someone will answer your question pretty quickly.